# Using google maps API or OpenLayer to render a large non-map image

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I have a large non-map image that I want to allow people to view on a browser at multiple zoom levels. I want to display the image in google maps API or openlayer so that people can zoom in/out and pan. I was hoping i could then add additional layers to overlay things of interest on the image. I am looking at MapTiler to chop the image up into tiles that can be generated at multiple zoom levels, but I'm getting very confused...

MapTiler wants to know about the spatial reference system (SRS) for georeferencing of my my image files, and well I don't know what I'm supposed to tell it ;) I have no georeference data - I just want it to generate tiles for my image, and then allow me to display that image in google maps or openlayer. In addition, openlayers seems very dependant on georeference data..

Am I looking at the wrong solution, or are there any pointers to getting this to work? Can OpenLayers be used to display a custom set of image tiles at multiple zoom levels without georefence data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. It is possible in both OpenLayers and Google maps to display a custom map, providing your own tiles for the map...

[This google groups posting](http://groups.google.com/group/maptiler/browse_thread/thread/7e8cd0ad890dc937) details how you can use MapTiler to generate non-georeferenced images, which can then be shown on a OpenLayers image.

In MapTiler, you need to choose rastor image and then ensure that you don't add any georeferencing data to the image with MapTiler.

Comment: A warning about Google maps though: you're at the mercy of Google.  I'm having to rewrite an interface (which other people wrote in GMaps 4 years ago) in OpenLayers because Google changed their API and broke our entire interface.  If you don't have time to keep up with Google's constantly-changing environment, I wouldn't go that way.  If you do though, Google might be better.

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right maybe [google maps custom overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) will fit your needs?

Comment: Cheers, I had that information already, but was looking for more information about how to generate tiles that could then be used with google maps or openlayers